# Setting title after aggregation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am trying to aggregate and count values together. Below you can see my dataset

```
data = {'id':['1','2','3','4','5'],
        'name': ['Company1', 'Company1', 'Company3', 'Company3', 'Company5'], 
        'sales': [10, 3, 5, 1, 0], 
        'income': [10, 3, 5, 1, 0], 
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['id','name', 'sales','income'])

conditions = [
    (df['sales'] < 1),
    (df['sales'] >= 1) & (df['sales'] < 3),
    (df['sales'] >= 3) & (df['sales'] < 5),
    (df['sales'] >= 5)
    ]


values = ['<1', '1-3', '3-5', '>= 5']

df['range'] = np.select(conditions, values)

df=df.groupby('range')['sales','income'].agg(['count','sum']).reset_index()
```

This code gives me the next table

[image]

But I am not satisfied with the appearance of this table because 'count' is duplicated two times. So can anybody help me with this table in order to have separate columns 'range', 'count', 'income' and 'sales'.

Comment: what do you mean by: "'count', 'income' and 'sales'"? aren't the "count" columns the count of "income" and "sales"?

Comment: No. Count actually counts the number of ranges. Other columns are sum.See this line of code df=df.groupby('range')['sales','income'].agg(['count','sum']).reset_index()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try named aggregation:

```
df.groupby('range', as_index=False).agg(count=('range','count'), sales=('sales','sum'), income=('income','sum'))
```

Output:

```
  range  count  sales  income
0   1-3      1      1       1
1   3-5      1      3       3
2    <1      1      0       0
3  >= 5      2     15      15
```

P.S. You probably want to make "range" a categorical variable, so that the output is sorted in the correct order:

```
df['range'] = pd.Categorical(np.select(conditions, values), categories=values, ordered=True)
```

Then the above code outputs:

```
  range  count  sales  income
0    <1      1      0       0
1   1-3      1      1       1
2   3-5      1      3       3
3  >= 5      2     15      15
```